# Is KDE 5 on Debian Stretch broken?

Tags: debian, kde5, plasma5

I had some problems after an update (krunner didn't work and kickoff search didn't either). I thought I had messed up things (had other problems not related to KDE) so I made a fresh install of the whole system, installing only KDE and Cinnamon as environments.

The problem with KDE is still there and I've got a new one.

Now I also have problems when connecting my laptop to a screen with HDMI, resulting in random disappearance of the main panel.
I never had problems with the displays before, and had one problem with krunner in the past that was solved by reinstalling KDE.

Shall I just wait for further updates or there's something I can do to get my menus back?

Comment: maybe.  stretch is currently the `testing` pre-release, after all.  its nature is to be broken or not broken.  sometimes it manages to be both at the same time.

Comment: @cas is correct -- testing is explicitly *described* as being unreliable because that's where Debian tests stuff until it's ready for the next stable release. It's actually *worse* than sid because in sid bugfixes don't have the ten-day wait. Basically, don't use testing unless you're actually testing thin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have always the very last packages of QT5, KF5 for every Plasma 5 version, or the Plasma Desktop has many bugs, freezes or is completely broken. In Debian are mostly old or different versions, also mixed with KDE 4, which ends up in multiple problems. So Plasma 5 in Debian is far away from usable. Personally i think, that KDE has no priority for Debian, but this minimalistic usability accident GNOME 3, is always up to date.

At this time, Plasma 5.6.5 with KF 5.22 under Debian is broken.

Krunner: broken, do nothing
Desktop-Search: broken, do nothing
Sound/Pulseaudio: broken, extremely often no sound,
Plasma Desktop: broken, opens windows without title bars always on the left upper edge, cant move or close windows, many crashes and so on

I think its better to wait when Plasma 5.10 or later is released, with Debian Stable 9.

Answer (score 5):

See bugreport: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=829614. There is some kind of conflicts between KF5 5.22 and 5.23.

I had the same issue, and installing libkf5plasma5 from unstable resolved it.

`apt install -t unstable libkf5plasma5`

Comment: `libkf5plasma5` was released in testing on [Fri, 22 Jul 2016](https://tracker.debian.org/news/786062). Resolved, for now.